# Data is not displaying on template (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, angular-services

I am practicing Angular by doing simple project. I see all Q&A on SO which is quite similar with my problem. Reason is that I am trying to display the async data before it initialized into `articles` variable, but I have tried `*ngIf` and `async` pipe.

**myService**

```
 public getArticlesByCategory(): Observable<any> {
   return this.request.get(this.categoryURL) 
  }
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
  public articles: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private articleService: ArticlesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.articleService.getArticlesByCategory().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.articles = data.articles; 
        console.log(this.articles)
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
  }
```

**template**

```
<div *ngIf="articles">
    <div *ngFor="let article of articles">
        <p>{{article.title}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your Error? Since everything looks good in code

Comment: It is not giving an error, i just cant loop through an array and displat the items

Comment: What does `console.log(this.articles)` display?

Comment: If I log it inside subscribe it logs the data but outside it logs the empty array

Comment: If `this.articles` was really an array and you didn't set "OnPush" as a ChangeDetectionStrategy, then your code would be working. I tested it in my local project. Maybe you should create a stackblitz-example, so it would be easier for us to see what the issue is.

Comment: I think you should share the link to the stackblitz code instead, since what you shared is basically just an empty page (probably the articles that don't load)?

Comment: As said before, the code provided should work. You don't even need the outer `ngIf` because you initialize the variable with an empty array. If anything the response is not valid (or has a structure you dont expect). Please share the log inside the `next` callback of `data.articles`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zf6dso?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I started with your stackblitz-example and added the `HttpClientModule` to the `app.module.ts`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fspqzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Add `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts` in `imports`

Comment: FYI: You cannot make API-calls from stackblitz, you have to mock them because of CORS-restrictions.

Comment: Your problem is solved now?

Comment: Not solved. I imported `HttpClientModule` in my actual source code, I will better share github link

Comment: https://github.com/Saidamir-Sh/news-app

Comment: `ng serve -c develop`

Comment: don't think there is any issue with your code. Only thing you need to see if data in your subscriber is correctly fetched from your API. 
check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7uhd6o?file=src/app/app.component.ts , data is coming good in template. The only thing is, data.json served locally in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Reviewing your code I found following errors:-

- In `app.routing.module.ts` in `rediretTo` add `pathMatch:'full'`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'articles', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'articles', component: ArticlesComponent },
];
```

- In `app.module.ts` add `ArticlesComponent` in declaration

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavbarComponent, ArticlesComponent],
  imports: [
    // CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [ArticlesService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```